# Restrict dates in 'datetimepicker' in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, datagridview, datetimepicker

A feature of a forms based application I am developing allows the user to search through a history of records.

The user can search by name, by number, and between dates, and populate the results in a datagridview control.

[image: Here is the form:]

However, as the form will be used to search for previous records. The ability for the user to select future dates is not required.

Is there a way to prevent the user from selecting future dates, or even grey the future dates out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with code based on `MaxDate`  property

```
yourControl.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`DateTimePicker.MaxDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) Property:

> ***DateTimePicker.MaxDate Property**: Gets or sets the maximum date and time that can be selected in the control.*

Answer (score 1):

Setting the MaxDate property will hide all dates after the specified date, and will not allow dates to be entered that are greater than that date.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx for details.